# CSS Select div without class in li element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I need to select this div and change width in `css` file. Question: how select this `div`?

```
.nav-pills > li > div.visible-md visible-lg{

    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
.nav-pills > li:nth-child(2) > div{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

.nav-pills > li:nth-child(2) > div{

}

Comment: Sorry for that. i saw same anwer once i have given answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the div without the class using the property "nth-child".
For eg:

```
.nav-pills > li:nth-child(2) > div{
/*sample*/
}
```